# Tap gesture not working on mobile android chrome

Tags: javascript, android, here-api

I coding a simple "add POIs"-javascript map, but how can i make Tap-gesture work on Android?

Tap gesture on HERE-api (JS) just does not work (using Samsung S10 and Chrome). You have tap dozen times to get tap recognized. This is an issue even with Here's own examples:
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/maps/position-on-mouse-click

With mouse everything works fine. With Android you have to tap many times. My guess is that Map Pan is activated that instead of Tap if your finger does even slight drag-movement while tapping.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-clustering.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>

    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        useCIT: true,
        app_id: 'foo',
        apikey: 'bar',
        useHTTPS: true
    });

    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'),
        defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
        {
            zoom: 6,
            pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
        });


    map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
        alert('tap'); // PROBLEM: only randomly works!
    });

    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

No errors are thrown but tapping doesn't popup alert.

Comment: Hi, would you please confirm your version of chrome? Please see Table 2. Browser support in HERE Maps API for JavaScript
 https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/overview.html

Comment: In Here Javascript 3.1 version api_id is not required.

Answer (score 0):

First, try only passing `apiKey` and not `app_id` to the Platform Service instance. Then please update your browser to the latest. For a complete working code with `tap` events please look at the updated code on: 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/maps/position-on-mouse-click